# Parse objects being deleted unexpectedly

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We have a chat system using Parse. We have a Conversation class, which itself has Messages.

No developer has touched the class but messages seem to be getting stripped back.

For example we have a Conversation:

**createdAt 2014-12-21**,

with its oldest remaining Message:

**createdAt 2014-12-30**

The only thing I can think of currently is we have a time-limit of 7 days on our Query, as such:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Conversation"];

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
if (user){
    [query whereKey:@"users" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[user]];
    NSDate *then = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-691191]; //7.9999 days in seconds
    [query whereKey:@"updatedAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:then];
    [query includeKey:@"users"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];

[...]
```

I wouldn't expect this to go ahead and delete data on Parse.com. I have disabled Delete access for now, to see if we stop 'leaking' data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Low and behold there was a method I wasn't aware of deleting old objects. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The default limit on a query is 100.  Querying a class with > 100 rows will give the appearance of lost data.  You can fix with any combination of: (a) setting the limit higher, up to 1000 (b) qualifying the query to generate fewer results and (c) successive queries paged using `query.skip = resultsFromLastQuery.count;`

Comment: Thanks but we're always under 100 rows. In this situation we only get 11. Also the data matches that found at parse.com, so it's not a query issue.

Comment: Do you mean that you create data, see it in the data browser, then return to the data browser later and its gone?

Comment: I mean we had been creating data for a while now, sending test messages back and forth, now when the messages are fetched the older messages are missing.

Visiting Parse.com and browsing the data confirms the rows have been removed.